# pinescript Draw a horizontal line with the opening price at a specific hour

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I would like to draw a horizontal line on the opening price of a bar at a certain hour, for example I draw a line on the opening price of the bar at 8 in the morning and it will be updated the next day at the same time.
Can anybody help me ??
Thank you

I don't know how to start, if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `hour` and `minute` variables to figure out if the current bar is 08:00.

Then store the open price in a `var` variable.

```
var float open_price = na
is_start = (hour == 8) and (minute == 0)

open_price := is_start ? open : open_price
plot(open_price)
```

Comment: And how do you draw the horizontal line, since when compiling it gives an error? Thanks

Comment: I test this code on pinescript v5, all is ok and the horizontal line is drawn.

Comment: @Tecleador what error are you getting? It should compile fine. Had tested it before posting my answer.

Comment: sorry for not answering sooner, what I need is an hline at the opening price of 8 in the morning but what you have given me does not show it to me
Thank you

Comment: and save the value of that opening to later create other hlines based on that value

Answer (score 0):

an example

```
//@version=5 indicator("Cotas Diarias", overlay=true)
_h = 2 // Hour: 7 _m = 0 // Minute: 0 inWindow = (hour(time) == _h) and 
(minute(time) == _m)
var line apertura = na var line R1 = na
if (inWindow) apertura := line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index + 1, open, 
extend=extend.right, color=color.rgb(4, 150, 41), width=4) 
line.delete(apertura[1])
```

That creates a horizontal line in the opening price of the bar at 8 in the morning and the next day it does the same